# Pandas: what does object type really mean?

Tags: pandas

I run df.dtypes and get for some columns the type "object". Does it mean Pandas can't tell what the column type is? or is it ok to proceed with analysis while keeping this type in the dataframe?
Is it part of cleaning data to make sure there is no type "object" left in the dataframe?

Comment: See pandas [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dtypes) on dtypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object is ok to use! You dont need to remove it.  df.dtypes is telling you that Numpy has described the column as "object", which is just a python object that most likely is a string type.

Answer (score 3):

`object`s are used to store strings in pandas. @Scott Boston already pointed at the documentation. Quoting from the [pandas doc on text-types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-types):

> There are two ways to store text data in pandas:
>
> 1. `object` -dtype NumPy array.
> 2. `StringDtype` extension type.
>
> We recommend using `StringDtype` to store text data.
>
> Prior to pandas 1.0, object dtype was the only option. This was unfortunate for many reasons...

Basically the reason are: (i) that `object` class can mix text and non-text, while `StringDtype` is dedicated for text; (ii) efficiency reasons; (iii) compatibility (with other libraries) reasons.

However, `StringDtype` is still experimental from what I read.

In my personal (5+ yrs) experience, I have never had trouble with `object` in data frames. It is perfectly fine to use them and you need not to remove them to have a cleaned data set. These are simply columns holding strings.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, type object is the default object type when items in that column are not matching in size. For example a column can contain strings of multiple sizes therefore its not uniform and python defaults it as a general object.

It is typically better to move forward with the cleaning process so you can better utilize memory / have a uniform object type.

Hope this helps!